In Grafana How To Create and Fill a 2D matrix
I am a beginner in Grafana. I have data grouped by pos_x and pos_y values and want to create a table in the form of an n x n matrix, where n is a fixed number. I want to fill the matrix cells based on their pos_x and pos_y values.
I have tried using the Grouping Matrix transformation, but the pos_x and pos_y values do not start from 0 and increment by 1; instead, the matrix only shows the existing pos_x and pos_y groups present in the data. I couldn't install XY charts and am currently unsure how to handle this. I can save pos_x and pos_y values as fields if needed.
How can I achieve the desired matrix visualization in Grafana?

I couldn't do this without a plugin. I used Business Charts where you can either use an SVG background, or simply use a scatterplot. I chose to use scatterplot for now. Then you query pos_x and pos_y values and combine them in a array of positions. Then use that as data in Scatterplot configurations
